# Save array of decimal values for using for loop

Tags: c#

I wanted to create an array of `increment_Num[]`, something like this:`[1.60,1.62,1.64,1.66,1.68,1.70]`

```
  //First step I converted the string to decimal value here:
  decimal Start_Num = decimal.Parse("1.60");
  decimal Stop_Num = decimal.Parse("1.70");
  decimal Steps_Num = decimal.Parse("0.02");
  
  //Second step I calculated the total number of points and converted the decimal value to int here:    
  decimal steps = (Stop_Num - Start_Num) /Steps_Num;
  int steps_int=(int)decimal.Ceiling(steps);
  
  //Third step I tried to create a for loop which will create an array       
  decimal[] increment_Num = new decimal[steps_int+1];
  for (decimal f=0; f<steps_int+1; f+=Steps_Num)
  {
  increment_Num[f] = Start_Num + f * Steps_Num;
  }
```

The following code gives me this error at the step-3 in the second last line for `increment_Num[f]`:

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Am I doing something wrong in declaration?

Comment: `increment_Num[f]` u use `f` as an index, arrays are indexed by int and f is a decimal

Comment: The moment I introduce int the for loop: for (int f=0; f<steps_int+1; f+=Steps_Num), it says that Steps_Num is decimal value. Which 0.02 in my case.

Comment: You aren't meant to increment by `Steps_Num`. You should increment by 1 as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posted my comment as answer :

`increment_Num[f]` u use `f` as an index, arrays are indexed by int and f is a decimal

The code should be

```
for (int index =0; index<=steps_int;  index++)
{   
    increment_Num[index] = Start_Num + index * Steps_Num;
}
```